# How do I log xargs -0 rm?

Tags: shell, xargs

I have a simple need to recursively find and delete files of a certain extension. So I have syntax that will find and remove the files and pipe them into `xargs -0 rm`, but I can't seem to create a log of the files that were removed.

What I have so far:

```
find /var/www/html -type f -regex ".*/.*\.(png|jpg)" -print0 |xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: What do you mean by "log"? What does your script do exactly? Please [edit] your question and show us a minimal example of the script and the kind of log you would like it to produce.

Comment: find /var/www/html -type f -regex ".*/.*\.\(png|jpg)" -print0 |xargs -0 rm

Comment: I'd like to send stdout and stderr to a file, is all.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to list the names of the files deleted as they are being removed?

Comment: Yes, or a list of deleted files.

Answer (score 2):

`rm` is normally silent when deleting files.  If you want to create a log showing files removed, add the `-v` option.  Thus, replace:

```
xargs -0 rm
```

with:

```
xargs -0 rm -v >log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` itself to delete files, and at the same time to write their names to stdout:

```
find /var/www/html -type f -regex ".*/.*\.\(png\|jpg\)" -delete -print >logfile
```

**Note:** Order of `-delete` and `-print` options is important. Second option will only be applied if first returns true, i.e. if first `-delete` option could not delete file, then its name will not be printed to stdout. If you put `-print` first, then it will put the filename to stdout regardless of  whether `-delete` could really delete the file.

**Note2**: I had to escape brackets and vertical line to make regex work by default with my system's `find` util. Alternatively, you can specify `-regextype` to `posix-egrep`, for example. Anyway, it worth first trying `find` command w/o `-delete` option to check whether it correctly finds files:

```
find /var/www/html -type f -regex ".*/.*\.\(png\|jpg\)" -print
```